# Evince - Libreoffice - Geogebra - Apparmor issues

Tags: libreoffice, pdf, evince, apparmor, okular

I try to authorize evince to open Geogebra and libreoffice files as links.

Using evince 3.18.2 on ubuntu 16.04.

**Update 1:** I've just installed a fresh 18.04 with the same problem.

**Update 2:** [Here are the files to try.](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/kx6kvo43v68vkkl/AAD6DOL2vF0pCoMKfuM83Jjia?dl=0) Both sort of links work fine with Okular.

For that I've added :

```
/usr/bin/geogebra ixr,
/usr/bin/libreoffice ixr,
```

just after :

```
# For text attachments
/usr/bin/gedit ixr,
```

in `usr.bin.evince` and ran : `sudo /etc/init.d/apparmor restart`

**On a libreoffice link, evince says :**

```
Impossible de lancer l'application externe.
L'exécution du processus fils « libreoffice » a échoué (Permission non accordée)
```

And no other message in the terminal from wich evince is launched.

**On a geogebra link, evince says nothing :**

but in the terminal windows from wich evince is launched there is the message:

```
/usr/bin/geogebra: ligne 9: /usr/bin/basename: Permission non accordée
/usr/bin/geogebra: /usr/share/geogebra/geogebra : /bin/bash : mauvais interpréteur: Permission non accordée
/usr/bin/geogebra: ligne 19: /usr/share/geogebra/geogebra: Succès
```

Geogebra is not launched but the icon in the launcher is blinking a while.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I give some tries on 18.04.1, for evince.

Add below lines into /etc/apparmor.d/local/usr.bin.evince

```
/usr/lib/libreoffice/program/* ixr,
/{usr/,}bin/* ixr,
```

You can see I use wildcard, I'm just lazy. You can explicitly specify all needed executables' path here. You should notice "/usr/bin/libreoffice" itself is a shell script. So all it launches is confined by rules of "usr.bin.evince"; I think it is same situation for geogebra

I'm not an expert of apparmor, maybe others have better idea.

**EDIT 1**

Another idea is, if you don't care apparmor's confinement, you can just put evince into complain mode, which will not confine its actions by:

```
$ sudo aa-complain /usr/bin/evince
```

in case you don't have aa-complain, you can install it by:

```
$ sudo apt install -y apparmor-utils
```

**EDIT 2**

Ok, since you have concerns of bypassing apparmor, I think you can do this:

1. Continue from my original answer, replace those wildcard with exact binary/script needed by /usr/bin/libreoffice - it is actually a symbolic link to /usr/lib/libreoffice/program/soffice;
2. Reload apparmor to update rules;
3. Do what you want to do in evince, and check shell output(or syslog) to see which executable is blocked, so you can add it into apparmor rules; Take your example of geogebra, you should add "/usr/bin/basename", "/bin/bash", "/usr/share/geogebra/geogebra" in your apparmor rules;
4. Repeat 2~4, until you don't see any problems.

Comment: It solves the libreoffice part. I don't know how to adapt this for geogebra, since geogebra script is launched but some calls in it are forbiden ?

Comment: @Tarass, do you really need apparmor to confine your apps? Maybe you can just simply put "/usr/bin/evince" to complain mode. See my update.

Comment: Thank you it solves the problem. Does some app can start automatically without clicking on a link ?

Comment: @Tarass, I think you mean to automatically launch some app by just opening a PDF file? It doesn't seems to be related to this question; You can start a new question, which I think it will receive wider readers.

Comment: It is an objection to your idea to put evince to complain mode. I ask you: is it safe or a pdf file opened in evince in complain mode could run a program without a click. You ask me "if I need apparmor", I ask you "do I need, or is it unsafe" ?

Comment: Ah, I misundertand your response, please check my update of guide to complete your apparmor rules.

Comment: Thank you very much. I had to add : ` /usr/bin/geogebra ixr,
  /usr/share/geogebra/geogebra ixr,
  /bin/bash ixr,
  /etc/geogebra/geogebra.conf ixr,
  /usr/bin/basename ixr,
  /usr/lib/jvm/java-geogebra/bin/java ixr,`
to make it work. You can complete your answer if you wish with this lines. Thanks again.